# AJAX problem - button click event fires after two clicks

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have an aspx page that is wrapped with an UpdatePanel control, users can post comments and delete them later, when the user clicks the delete for the first time it deletes successfully but if he wants to delete another comment, it works only after two clicks on the button.
the delete button is inside a web user control that is added dynamically at run time.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a simple, but working example of the problem?

Comment: Do you get any script errors? Can you check with fiddler to see if a HTTP request was generated for each button click?

Answer (score 0):

I had a bit different problem. The control event did not work at all after AJAX post back. Here is the possible solution to your problem - http://sharepointtechie.blogspot.com/2011/04/click-event-stopped-firing-after-ajax.html

Answer (score 0):

Please register that control during page load event of the control..

So if you are calling `usercontrol1` dynamically during the runtime..

then on the page load event of usercontrol.ascx you should have

```
this.id="xyz";
```

try this... It did some miracle for us...
Hope this works for you too